# VBScript to combine rs values, loop and add to duplicate(s)

Tags: vbscript

I've written a lot of IF statements in VBScript, but haven't gone much beyond that so apologize for my lack of experience. I hope what I'm asking is simple to do.

I want to output item identifiers created by three combined recordset field values and add "B" "C" "D" etc., to any duplicates. Duplicates are rare, but do happen occasionally. I want to do this for meaningful item identification which autonumbers do not provide.

The following example works to combine fields, but then I need to include script to loop and find the duplicates and add the appropriate alpha character.

FYI: a = alpha character, b = alpha character, c = reformatted date

```
 <% Dim idCode
 a = (rs_table.Fields.Item("CodeA").Value) 
 b = (rs_table.Fields.Item("CodeB").Value)
 c = (fixedDate(rs_table.Fields.Item("Date").Value))
 idCode = (a) & (b) & (c)
 Response.write idCode
 %>
```

example output: LC032414
example dupe output:  LC032414B

Thanks, I'm almost afraid to ask and may find this more pain than what it's worth!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a `Dictionary` to store the ID's, since you can add each as a key (which must be unique) and test the `Dictionary` for its existence. Something like this:

```
' Early on... create a dictionary...
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Loop through your records...
Do Until rs_table.EOF

    ' Determine your ID...
    idCode = rs_table("CodeA") & rs_table("CodeB") & fixedDate(rs_table("Date"))

    ' Check for existence in the dictionary...
    If d.Exists(idCode) Then

        ' ID already exists. Keep testing suffixes until we find an availability...
        strLetter = "B"

        Do While d.Exists(idCode & strLetter)
            strLetter = Chr(Asc(strLetter) + 1)
        Loop

        d.Add idCode & strLetter, ""    ' Add the ID/key. The value is unimportant.

    Else

        ' This ID doesn't exist yet. Just add it.
        d.Add idCode, ""    ' Add the ID/key. The value is unimportant.

    End If

    rs_table.MoveNext

Loop
```

When it comes time to print your ID's, you can just iterate the dictionary's `Keys` collection:

```
For Each k In d.Keys
    Response.Write k
Next
```

Comment: +1 for recommending dictionaries when dealing with duplicates, (at least implicitly) initializing the collection *before* the loop, *not* keeping the OT's lispy (), and tackling the problem of *marking* the dups.

Comment: Okay, so this script makes logical sense to me except when it comes to calling the dictionary's Keys collection to print the IDs - I obviously need to replace the "k" with something? All my IDs now have the same date.  This is all new to me so I need a lot of hand-holding.

Comment: The `k` is just a generic variable. If you have `Option Explicit` declared, you'll need to dim it first (`Dim k`). During iteration, it's assigned each key value (string), in turn. Also, maybe it wasn't clear from my code, but everything in the first code block (with the exception of the dictionary creation) should be within your recordset loop so that you're testing each record in turn.

Comment: I've added the recordset loop to the original code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study this code and read up on dictionaries so I understand better. :)